# remove content between parentheses using python regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file like -

```
{[a] abc (b(c)d)}
```

I want to remove the content between these bracket `[] and (())`. so the output should be -

```
 abc
```

I removed the content between parentheses but could not remove the content between this `[]` 
I have tried below code -

```
import re

with open('data.txt') as f:
    input = f.read()
    line = input.replace("{","")
    line = line.replace("}","")
    output = re.sub(r'\(.*\)', "", line)
    print output
```

The output is -

```
[a] abc
```

In my code first I replace the `{}` and then remove the content from `()` . I want to add `\[.*\]` in `output = re.sub(r'\(.*\)', "", line)` this line . But could not find a way to do this. I am still learning python. So I am facing this problem. please help.

Comment: You did `\(.*\)`. You could do `\[.*\]` too.

Comment: Just a remark not directly related to this: python regexes are not really good at processing *balanced* bracketted expressions...

Comment: @khelwood i have edited my question.

Comment: @Jan: I know about it, but AFAIK the standard library only contains the old `re` module and OP has an `import re` line...

Comment: @revo thanx, I did this `output = re.sub(r'\(.*\)', "", line)
    output = re.sub(r'\[.*\]', "", output)`  with this two lines. But is there any way to do this  in one line?

Comment: All your replacements could be shortened to `re.sub(r'[{}]|\(.*\)|\[.*\]', "", line)`

Comment: Thank you @revo . +1 for this answer :)

Comment: ok! @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may check if a string contains `[`, `]`, `(<no_parentheses_here>)` or `[no_brackets_here]` substrings and remove them while there is a match.

```
import re                                    # Use standard re
s='{[a] abc (b(c)d)}'
rx = re.compile(r'\([^()]*\)|\[[^][]*]|[{}]')
while rx.search(s):                          # While regex matches the string
    s = rx.sub('', s)                        # Remove the matches
print(s.strip())                             # Strip whitespace and show the result
# => abc
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/xL1oC4)

It will also work with paired nested `(...)` and `[...]`, too.

**Pattern details**

- `\([^()]*\)` - `(`, then any 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`, and then `)`
- `|` - or
- `\[[^][]*]` - `[`, then any 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`, and then `]`
- `|` - or
- `[{}]` - a character class matching `{` or `}`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :) @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: @jahan You may also reduce whitespaces if you prepend the pattern with `\s*`: `re.compile(r'\s*(?:\([^()]*\)|\[[^][]*]|[{}])')`

Comment: I have another question. In my text file the first line is `[abcdef]` and the second line is {[a] abc (b(c)d)}  . So when I use this regex it removes the first line and makes an empty space on the first line . Outputs are like in first line - `1.                 `  and in second line `2. abc`.    I used strip() and lsrtip() but could not remove the blank spaces which is created in the first line. How can I solve this problem? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @jahan Can you please create  a code demo? I am not quite sure I understand what you mean. If you read the contents from a file into a string, that should not be a problem. If strip does not work, that may be not a whitespace at all, but some LTR or RTL marks, or other weird Unicode chars. Also, try `re.sub(r'^\W+|\W+$', '', s)`

Answer (score 4):

Imo not as easy as it first might look, you'd very likely need some balanced (recursive) approach which could be achieved with the [**newer `regex` module**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/):

```
import regex as re

string = "some lorem ipsum {[a] abc (b(c)d)} some other lorem ipsum {defg}"

rx_part = re.compile(r'{(.*?)}')
rx_nested_parentheses = re.compile(r'\((?:[^()]*|(?R))*\)')
rx_nested_brackets = re.compile(r'\[(?:[^\[\]]*|(?R))*\]')

for match in rx_part.finditer(string):
    part = rx_nested_brackets.sub('', 
        rx_nested_parentheses.sub('', 
            match.group(1))).strip()
    print(part)
```

Which would yield

```
abc
defg
```

---

The pattern is

```
\(         # opening parenthesis
(?:        # non.capturing group
    [^()]* # not ( nor )
    |      # or
    (?R)   # repeat the pattern
)*
\)
```

Comment: Your answer is indeed correct and informative. I simply wonder whether it is required here. OP did not say what should be done with unbalanced expression. +1 anyway for the recursive regex example...

Comment: @SergeBallesta: Thanks, let's wait and see what OP really wants.

Comment: @Jan Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

i tried this and i got your desired output...i hope i got you right

```
import re

with open('aa.txt') as f:
    input = f.read()
    line = input.replace("{","")
    line = line.replace("}","")
    output = re.sub(r'\[.*\]', "", line)
    output = re.sub(r'\(.*\)', "", output)
    print(output)
```