# Remove text between opening and closing symbols

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Let's say I have a string in which I want to remove text between parentheses (and the parentheses themselves). For example:

```
input:  'Lorem ipsum (dolor) sit amet'
output: 'Lorem ipsum  sit amet'
```

In general, I would like to remove text between any given couple of opening and closing symbols. For example, if my list of symbols is `['()', '[]', '<>']` then

```
input:  '(Lorem) <ipsum> dolor [sit amet]'
output: '  dolor '
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14599280/5296106) answer is of course very related, and simple enough. However, it does have a huge problem: it does not work in cases in which different types of parentheses are used together within the string. For example, the linked answer fails in this case:

```
input:  '(Lorem ipsum] dolor) sit amet'
output: ' sit amet'
```

Indeed, that solution provides the output `' dolor) sit amet'`.

Does anybody know if this problem can be solved with a regex?

---

Some more details. In my specific case, there can't be overlapping matches. For example, this case is **not** possible:

```
'(Lorem [ipsum) dolor] sit amet'
```

Also, there can't be nested matches. So these cases are **not** possible:

```
'(Lorem ipsum (dolor sit)) amet'
'(Lorem [ipsum] dolor) sit amet'
```

Comment: You may try `r'\([^()]*\)|\[[^][]*]|<[^<>]*>'`

Comment: What is your preferred output in the case "<[a(b]c<d)e>"

Comment: What should be output in case of `(Lorem] ipsum dolor sit amet`?

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 You're right. Let me simplify the problem by adding that there can't be overlapping matches (like `'(Lorem [ipsum) dolor] sit amet'`. Also, there can't be nested matches. Let me update the question

Comment: @Daweo `(Lorem] ipsum dolor sit amet`

Comment: Ok, so my solution will work.

Comment: But all you need is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49915974/remove-content-between-parentheses-using-python-regex), it is all about the same, you just have angle brackets instead of braces, still, same pattern scheme is used.